# how to use BigInt for a modified Fibonacci

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, biginteger

**I am trying to solve this:** [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-modified)

And by Dynamic programming I am able to solve the problem, here is the code so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Dy
    {
        static long[] storage = new long[20];
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);

            storage[0] = sx.nextInt();
            storage[1] = sx.nextInt();
            int x = sx.nextInt();

            System.out.println(beast(x-1));


        }

    public static long beast(int n)
    {
        if(n==0)
            return storage[n];
        if(n==1)
            return storage[n];

        if(storage[n]!=0)
            return storage[n];

        storage[n] = (beast(n-1)*beast(n-1)) + beast(n-2);

        return storage[n];
    }
}
```

But the **real trouble** here is , if n is say around 20, even `long` data type won't hold the value, so the choice is obviously `BigInteger` , but as a learner, I was wondering how to use `BigInteger` with Arrays in Java? Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Map<Integer, BigInteger>` and something like,

```
static Map<Integer, BigInteger> storage = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sx = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Add 0 and 1.
    storage.put(0, BigInteger.valueOf(sx.nextInt()));
    storage.put(1, BigInteger.valueOf(sx.nextInt()));
    int x = sx.nextInt();

    System.out.println(beast(x - 1));
}

public static BigInteger beast(int n) {
    if (!storage.containsKey(n)) {
        BigInteger t = beast(n - 1);
        storage.put(n, t.multiply(t).add(beast(n - 2)));
    }
    return storage.get(n);
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's more like a real nice simplified Dynamic Programming , thank you, btw I was wondering where to begin reading about BigIntegers in Java? The other questions and tutorials just seems a bit incomplete, any suggestion with that will be much helpful, Thanks :)

Comment: The [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) Javadoc.

Comment: I don't know Java very well, but wouldn't a simple array be much easier (and probably faster) than a map? ISTM that they map consecutive integers to their element types very well.

Comment: Java arrays are fixed lenght

Comment: What about an ArrayList?